# Cordova Phonegap Json Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to create an app with phonegap.

When I create a JSON request and run it directly on my webserver it works just fine but in Cordova Phonegap the select field doesn't get filled.

I use the ripple chrome plugin to simulate the app.

What am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

```html
<select class="form-control  dealsearchselect" id='com' style='height: 50px; width: 100%;'>

</select>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let dropdown = $('#com');

  dropdown.empty();

  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Selecteer</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

  const url = 'https://url/com_json.php';

  // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name));
    })
  });

});

</script>
```

This is the data provided from JSON

```json
[
  {
    "id":"52",
    "name":"Huishouden, Gezin en Dier"
  },
  {
    "id":"20",
    "name":"Dienstverlening"
  },
  {
    "id":"29",
    "name":"Kleine reparaties"
  },
  {
    "id":"62",
    "name":"Training en Educatie"
  },
  {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Huis en Tuin"
  },
  {
    "id":"73",
    "name":"Artistiek"
  },
  {
    "id":"77",
    "name":"Amusement en Workshops"
  },
  {
    "id":"43",
    "name":"Auto en Vervoer"
  },
  {
    "id":"86",
    "name":"Welzijn en Verzorging"
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks fine.  Is jQuery included in the project or is it a CDN?

Comment: i am using a CDN

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the content security policy meta tag to the `head` section of your `index.html` file to allow unsafe inline Javascript execution? Try this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *; default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap: data: ms-appdata: blob: file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
```

Also, why don't you run and debug the app on the device directly to see the errors in real time? You can easily [debug the app on devices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k9ZGXvV2PY) using [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Comment: adding the <meta> line didnt help, ill check out the debugging link thx

Comment: I get an "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access"  in visual studio

Comment: Its kind of weird, got it working in visual studio but cant get it to work on phonegap :(